# RANK operating failing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have not had any success getting the `RANK` operator to work in pig version 0.12.1. Thought I would post here before raising a bug report.

Here is my very simple script:

```
InputData = LOAD '$in' USING PigStorage('\u0001') AS (a1:chararray, a2:chararray, score:float);
Ranked = RANK InputData BY score DESC DENSE;
OutputData = FOREACH Ranked GENERATE
    rank_InputData AS rank,
    a1 AS a1,
    score AS score;
STORE OutputData INTO '$out' using PigStorage('\u0001');
```

I've run this with two different versions of input:

- $in contains 4700 input paths
- $in contains 60 input paths

These inputs contain the same data (280M rows, 25GB) except that the second input has the data aggregated into a smaller number of files (motivated by [this thread related to a counters-per-mapper issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201304.mbox/%3CCAKcT+0atdSBBH-XX8Zf5+Br6uxsmAAuCKgaZnxmYuJfWnt_UHg@mail.gmail.com%3E)).

The result ("Java heap space" error) is the same for both inputs:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
Error: Java heap space

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:148)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:478)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

I have tried another version of the script, that uses `ORDER ... BY` to do some of the work:

```
InputData = LOAD '$in' USING PigStorage('\u0001') AS (a1:chararray, a2:chararray, score:float);
InputDataOrdered = ORDER InputData BY score DESC PARALLEL 60;
Ranked = RANK InputDataOrdered;
OutputData = FOREACH Ranked GENERATE
    rank_InputDataOrdered AS rank,
    a1 AS a1,
    score AS score;
STORE OutputData INTO '$out' using PigStorage('\u0001');
```

Both inputs give the same error, this time "too many counters":

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2043: Unexpected error during execution.
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading responses
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:843)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.checkCounters(Limits.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.incrCounters(Limits.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.readFields(AbstractCounterGroup.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters$Group.readFields(Counters.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.readFields(AbstractCounters.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:952)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:836)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Enumerate UDF in DataFu library when you make ranking field.

```
register 'datafu-1.2.0.jar';
define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');

A = load 'test.dat' using PigStorage() AS ( f1:int, f2:int);

A = group A ALL;

A = foreach A {
        sorted = order A by f1 DESC, f2 ASC;
        generate group, sorted;
}

B = foreach A generate FLATTEN( Enumerate( sorted ));

dump  B;  <- ( f1, f2, rank)
```

refer to http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.html